# nanoScroller not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to use `nanoScroller` in my project. I am going by the documentation at the [official site](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/). This is the code I have come up with (the `nano.js` contains the same code as at the [production site](https://raw.github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS/master/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js) mentioned in that page. However, it is not working, and the text is simply overflowing the container. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="nano.js">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS/master/bin/css/nanoscroller.css">
        <style>
             .nano { width: 500px; height: 200px;}
             .nano .content { padding: 10px;  }
             .nano .pane   { background: black; }
             .nano .slider { background: #111; }
        </style>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                     $(".nano").nanoScroller();
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="about" class="nano">
        <div class="content"> 
            Thanks to SublimeVideo Horizon, the SublimeVideo Modular Player can now easily be enriched with future features and add-ons. Below, we would like to share with you some possible upcoming features and add-ons. We would be delighted if you let us know about any other add-on you may need.Thanks to SublimeVideo Horizon, the SublimeVideo Modular Player can now easily be enriched with future features and add-ons. Below, we would like to share with you some possible upcoming features and add-ons. We would be delighted if you let us know about any other add-on you may need.Thanks to SublimeVideo Horizon, the SublimeVideo Modular Player can now easily be enriched with future features and add-ons. Below, we would like to share with you some possible upcoming features and add-ons. We would be delighted if you let us know about any other add-on you may need.Thanks to SublimeVideo Horizon, the SublimeVideo Modular Player can now easily be enriched with future features and add-ons. Below, we would like to share with you some possible upcoming features and add-ons. We would be delighted if you let us know about any other add-on you may need.Thanks to SublimeVideo Horizon, t
        </div> 
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in console ? Also, I'm not sure `raw.github.com` allows direct access to code.

Comment: So you saying that I copy the `css` also to a separate file? Okay, doing it. And no, no error in console..

Comment: Gee, it works! The `css` file was not being accessed..But in Firefox, when I was viewing the source code, the `github` link was properly highlighted as an external link, and clicking it was displaying the page. Why then can't it be accessed?

Comment: Yes, direct access is allowed (with the full url) but not through another website (crossdomain). I added this as an answer since this was the issue.

Comment: Cool. I always thought that if cross domain access were not allowed, the link wouldn't be highlighted in the source..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.github.com` is not a CDN and so does not allows remote access from another website. Download the CSS file to your server and change your `<link rel="stylesheet" />` so.